# VS 2008 pages open to left

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I open a page(.aspx,xslt,css..etc) from the solution explorer in VS 2008 , it opens to the left of my current active tab. I am used to VS2003/VS2005 where the new page opens up to the right of current active page. How do i set all the pages to open to the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, under Tools > Options > Environment > Documents:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can't be done in VS 2005/VS 2008

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=360962
http://www.codeverge.net/ng.asp-net-forum.visual_studio_2005/order-of-document-tabs-in-vs-2005

Pretty sad...its very tough getting used to this behavior