# VS2008: Changing Default Right-to-Left Tab Ordering of Documents in IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In VisualStudio 2008, if I open, from the solution explorer, the source files A.cs, B.cs and then C.cs, the tabs in the document area will be C, B, A.

To get the tabs ordered A, B, C, I'd have to open them in this order: C, B, A.

Is there a way to have new document tabs appear to the right of existing tabs? (Like the way it used to work in VS2005?)

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306971/vs-2008-pages-open-to-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, under Tools > Options > Environment > Documents:

[image]